# Video Mixing Renderer 9 quality issue

Tags: winapi, video, directshow

I have a fairly simple question. Or at least I thought I would be simple to solve but couldn't find any answers online.

Anyway

1. I used this example form MSDN to play a file using DirectShow:
   [How To Play a File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd389098). 
   It's really simple with only a few lines of code and it works.
2. Then after some research I managed to create a VMR9 filter and add it to the graph. This also worked.

There's just one thing

When I play a video file using the VMR9 filter the quality looks worse in VMR9.

I tried changing it with IVMRMixerControl9::SetMixingPrefs but nothings seems to change. `IVMRMixerControl9::SetMixingPrefs` does actually return S_OK.

```cpp
dwPrefs &= ~MixerPref9_FilteringMask;
dwPrefs |= MixerPref9_BiLinearFiltering;
```

Or am I using the wrong filter?

**edit: problem solved**

I just did a comparison with Media Player Classic by putting it on VMR9 (windowed) mode. It gave me the same quality. So if I want better quality am gonna have to use EVR (enhanced video rendering) instead of VMR9 (Video Mixing Renderer 9).

Answer (score 1):

VMR-7/VMR-9 quality issues are a long standing problem:

- [Poor Picture Quality with VMR9 as renderer](http://www.avsforum.com/t/1129937/poor-picture-quality-with-vmr9-as-renderer)
- [VMR9 scaling issues on Vista](http://forum.inmatrix.com/index.php?showtopic=6513)

EVR [is suggested](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374574) to be used instead, to get proper/nicer scaling and visual picture quality.

> In Windows Vista and later, applications should use the EVR if the hardware supports it. Otherwise, fall back to the VMR-9 or VMR-7. The EVR offers better performance **and better video quality than previous renderers**. Also, it is designed to work with the Desktop Window Manager (DWM).

Better performance is questionable, and EVR is sadly having its own issues though, but when output quality is in question EVR is the answer.